# How to install vim-emu in Fedora 39?

Tags: linux, networking, fedora, sdn

I tried to install vim-emu in Fedora 39 but it doesn't work what to do?

I tired to install
sudo apt-get install ansible git aptitude
cd
git clone https://github.com/containernet/containernet.git
cd ~/containernet/ansible
sudo ansible-playbook -i "localhost," -c local install.yml
cd ..
sudo make develop
cd
git clone https://osm.etsi.org/gerrit/osm/vim-emu.git
cd ~/vim-emu/ansible
sudo ansible-playbook -i "localhost," -c local install.yml
cd ..
sudo python3 setup.py develop

Comment: sudo dnf install vim

Comment: What's the error are you seeing?